# Getting array of array objects, want array of the sequences

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, google-colaboratory

The array I'm aiming for looks like this one:

```
array([[[0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333]],

       [[0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333]],

       [[0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.77777778]]])
```

I'm receiving the following array:

```
array([array([[0.77777778],
       [0.77777778],
       [0.77777778],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333]]),
       array([[0.77777778],
       [0.77777778],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333]]),
       array([[0.77777778],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.77777778]])], dtype=object)
```

What kind of data manipulation could I do to achieve this?

For some reason Google Colab is appending the sequences properly to the first array then making an array of array objects for the second one, the code for creating the arrays is identical. It treats the second array as if I ran np.split to produce an array of array objects.

Here is the code to produce the above arrays:

```
def walk_forward_train(X, stepsBack, stepsForward, trainTestSplit):
  n_records = len(X)
  X = X[:]
  split = int(n_records*trainTestSplit-stepsForward)
  x = []
  y = []
  for i in range(n_records):
    x.append(X[i : i + stepsBack])  
    y.append(X[i + stepsBack : i + stepsBack + stepsForward])

  xtrain = x[:split]
  ytrain = y[:split]

  xtest = x[: n_records - stepsForward]
  ytest = y[: n_records - stepsForward]
    
  return np.asarray(xtrain), np.asarray(ytrain), np.asarray(xtest), np.asarray(ytest)
```

**Edit:**
Here is a link to a Github I made to recreate this issue:
https://github.com/Crayfi/Datasets

Comment: You aren't showing us the full array, are you?  This looks like a repeat of a question a few days back, where I suspected the subarrays varied in shape.  I still think that's the issue.

Comment: From the notebook you are showing `np.array(X_test)[:3]`, not all of `X_test`.

Answer (score 1):

```
your_old_array = array([array([[0.77777778],
       [0.77777778],
       [0.77777778],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333]]),
       array([[0.77777778],
       [0.77777778],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333]]),
       array([[0.77777778],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.83333333],
       [0.77777778]])], dtype=object)

req_array = your_old_array.astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: This threw the error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: The error tells us that your source array contains arrays that differ in shape.  It cannot be made into a multidimensional numeric array.  Check the individual array shapes.

Comment: @WillisAllen what are the inputs for the walk_forward_train() function? We cannot generate the data. My answer assumes you have the "your_old_array" data and you want in a multidimensional numeric array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
np.asarray(your_old_array)
```

output:

```
array([[[0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333]],

       [[0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333]],

       [[0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.77777778]]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Calling `np.array` again on an `object` dtype array is not going to change it.   Be careful when trying to recreate a problem with a simple copy-n-paste.  You may not be reproducing the OP's starting case.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do at first when I returned all the arrays with np.asarray(). I tried creating the above array in a new code block in Colab and after runnng np.asarray() on it it gave the expected array but running it on the array I get from my dataset returns the array of array objects.

Answer (score 0):

Taking care to ensure that the copy-n-paste produces a 3 element object array:

```
In [383]: array=np.array
In [384]: list=[array([[0.77777778],
     ...:        [0.77777778],
     ...:        [0.77777778],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333]]),
     ...:        array([[0.77777778],
     ...:        [0.77777778],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333]]),
     ...:        array([[0.77777778],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.83333333],
     ...:        [0.77777778]])]
```

create an 3 element object array, and fill it from the list:

```
In [385]: arr = np.empty(3,object)
In [386]: arr[:] = list
In [387]: arr
Out[387]: 
array([array([[0.77777778],
              [0.77777778],
              [0.77777778],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333]]), 
       array([[0.77777778],
              [0.77777778],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333]]),
       array([[0.77777778],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.83333333],
              [0.77777778]])], dtype=object)
```

This is a 1d array, with all element arrays the same shape.  `stack` will work:

```
In [388]: np.stack(arr)
Out[388]: 
array([[[0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333]],

       [[0.77777778],
        [0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333]],

       [[0.77777778],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.83333333],
        [0.77777778]]])
```

If `stack` does not work like this, then you are not showing us the real array.  In fact looking at the notebook I see that you only show [:3], **without** telling us.  You've tried to pass it off as the whole array!

Copied from the notebook display:

```
In [41]:
np.array(X_test)[:3]
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: 
Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or 
ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 
'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

That's telling you what I've been trying say all along, the arrays in `X_test` do not all have the same shape.

You've been wasting our time and yours with three incomplete questions!